# 'Ember new' throws 'cannot find module' error Windows 10

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm

I'm trying to learn ember and had an install that worked fine. Not sure what happened but suddenly Ember new would throw the following error:

```
$ ember new app
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ConquerJS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\cli\index.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I tried to manually install the missing modules but then the same error comes up again with a new module it can't find. I get this error in git bash and windows cmd running both as administrator.

I was so at a loss and in desperate need to get up and running with ember today that **I reinstalled windows** on my machine thinking this would get things working like they did earlier in the day, but I still get the error. I updated npm to the latest version and still get it. Now I get it as soon as I type ember -v even though it worked on an earlier install.

I thought maybe something happened with npm so I went on my old desktop and installed ember and it works fine (but unacceptably slow on its old amd processor and hdd).

Comment: What versions of node/npm? [Currently, Ember CLI supports Node (4.0 recommended) and npm (2.x).](https://ember-cli.com)

Comment: Node 4.5.0 and npm 3.10.7. But Now I managed to get things working. Not sure if this did the trick but I installed ember-cli-windows which I learned about from a microsoft virtual academy tutorial on ember .

Comment: why/how did you start a new project inside the Users directory?

Comment: That was a mistake which I corrected later (because I'm a noob).